# Controlling CSS Transform with an external button?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, css-transforms

Need help with a javascript on a button to trigger these transformations like a slider 1,2,3 and alternate back and forth. Like on the apple website for iPhone features slider. Anyone?

The HTML:

```
<div id="anima-slide1">
  <div class="anima-text-slide1">Genuinity comes at a price.<br>
    <font color="#f06">Will you pay it?</font></div>
  <div class="anima-image-slide1"><img src="img/lowrider1.png" width="250" height="250"> </div>
</div>

<div id="anima-slide2">
  <div class="anima-text-slide2">Genuinity comes at a price.<br>
    <font color="#f06">Will you pay it?</font></div>
  <div class="anima-image-slide2"><img src="img/lowrider1.png" width="250" height="250"> </div>
</div>

<div id="anima-slide3">
  <div class="anima-text-slide3">Genuinity comes at a price.<br>
    <font color="#f06">Will you pay it?</font></div>
  <div class="anima-image-slide3"><img src="img/lowrider1.png" width="250" height="250"> </div>
</div>
```

The CSS: (Same for 2 and 3)

```
.anima-text-slide1 {
    margin-top:10px;
    position:absolute;
    font-family: 'BebasRegular';
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:40px;
}
.anima-text-slide1 {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: 900ms ease;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-497px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
}
.anima-image-slide1 {
    position:absolute;
    left: 610px;
    top: 0px;
}
.anima-image-slide1 {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: 900ms ease;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate(497px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you want to do?

Comment: I want CSS Transforms to take place on the click of a button. like a JQuery slider but with css and instead of slides coming and going I want animations to come and go. Using Next and previous buttons you can navigate various animated slides. 

Something like this: http://www.apple.com/iphone/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a class name you can create several animation steps. Using jQuery makes it a lot easier to change the class names on the target element. You can apply this technique to your particular situation.

```
<div class="container">
Hello
</div>

<a href="javascript://" onclick="setFrame('frame1')">Frame 1</a>
<a href="javascript://" onclick="setFrame('frame2')">Frame 2</a>
```

JS:

```
function setFrame(frameName) {
    $('.container').addClass(frameName);
}
```

CSS:

```
.container {
     font-size:24px;   
}    
.frame1 {
    font-size:48px;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: 900ms ease;
    opacity: 20;
    -webkit-transform: translate(200px, 0px) rotate(0deg);
}
.frame2 {
    font-size:64px;
    color:#ff0000;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transition: 900ms ease;
    opacity: 20;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px, 150px) rotate(30deg);
}
```

**EDIT:**

So if you want to do multiple elements you can do something like this:

```
.containerA .frame1 {
... 
} 

.containerB .frame1 {
...some different style... 
}
```

Then:

```
   function setFrame(frameName) {
        $('.containerA').addClass(frameName);
        $('.containerB').addClass(frameName);
    }
```